# Clojure dialog box for file selection with filter for files' extensions

Tags: java, swing, clojure, jfilechooser

This is a continuous crawling for a lipster beginner on Clojure and Java.
I have this code to select a file, but I would like to filter the files' extensions that I am looking for.

```
(import javax.swing.JFileChooser)
(defn tlt-get-file [ ]
       (let [ filechooser (JFileChooser. "C:/") 
              retval (.showOpenDialog filechooser nil) ]
          (if (= retval JFileChooser/APPROVE_OPTION)
             (do 
                (println (.getSelectedFile filechooser))
                (.getSelectedFile filechooser))
              "")))
```

Your help always much appreciated.

Comment: If you're planning on spending much time doing UIs in Clojure, you'll want to take a look at a lib like Seesaw (https://github.com/daveray/seesaw). There, this is just `(choose-file :dir "C:/" :filters [["Images" ["png" "jpeg"]]])`. Welcome to Clojure :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(import '(javax.swing JFileChooser)
        '(javax.swing.filechooser FileNameExtensionFilter))
(defn tlt-get-file [ ]
       (let [ extFilter (FileNameExtensionFilter. "Text File" (into-array  ["txt"]))
              filechooser (JFileChooser. "C:/")
              dummy (.setFileFilter filechooser extFilter)
              retval (.showOpenDialog filechooser nil) ]
          (if (= retval JFileChooser/APPROVE_OPTION)
             (do 
                (println (.getSelectedFile filechooser))
                (.getSelectedFile filechooser))
              "")))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to [set the file filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileFilter%28javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter%29), which you can do either by extending the [FileFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) class, or using a built-in implementation like [FileNameExtensionFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html). Note that the FNEF takes variable arguments in Java, which means that it takes an array in actual JVM bytecode. So something like

```
(FileNameExtensionFilter. 
 "Text files only"
 (into-array ["txt"]))
```

would be a simple, reasonable filter.

Or if you would rather do something more specialized, like only accept extensions which have a J in them, you can implement the filtering yourself. Sadly, Java chose to make this a 100% abstract class instead of an interface, so you can't use reify. In an ideal world you could write

```
(reify java.io.FileFilter
  (getDescription [this] "Java loves Js!")
  (accept [this f]
    (boolean (re-find #"\..*j[^.]*$" (.getName f)))))
```

but Java loves classes, so instead you need

```
(proxy [java.io.FileFilter] []
  (getDescription [] "Java loves Js!")
  (accept [f]
    (boolean (re-find #"\..*j[^.]*$" (.getName f)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your very fast answer amalloy!! As I said, excuse my ignorance, but I am 'crawling' on Clojure and have zip Java experience. My question is how do I implement your solutions into my code?

Comment: `(.setFileFilter filechooser (some-file-filter-thingy))` before you open the dialog. That should be all it takes.